# Injecting settings into AutoMapper profile

Tags: entity-framework, dependency-injection, json.net, asp.net-core, automapper

I'm using asp.net core to implement REST service with an entity framework as ORM, the out-of-the box dependency injection and AutoMapper to convert my data models into view-models.
My data model looks something like this:

```
public class Entity{
   [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   public int EntityId {get;set;}
   [StringLength(50)]
   public string Name {get;set;}
   [StringLength(4000)]
   public string EntityMetadata {get;set;}
}

public class EntityMetadata{
   public string Property {get;set;}
   public int OtherProperty {get;set;}
}

public class EntityViewModel{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public EntityMetadata EntityMetadata {get;set;}
}
```

I store metadata as a JSON formatted string in the DB for flexibility but want it to be exposed to the client as a strongly typed model. For this purposes I have created an AutoMapper profile.

```
public class EntityProfile : Profile{
  public EntityProfile(JsonSerializerSettings settings) : {
     CreateMap<EntityViewModel,Entity>
        .ForMember(e=>e.EntityMetadata, m=>m.ResolveUsing(
            c=>JsonConvert.SerializeObject(c.EntityMetadata, settings)))
  }
}
```

The problem I'm a facing is that I cannot figure out how to configure AutoMapper and MVC so that they will share the same instance of JsonSerializerSettings.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
   var mvcBuilder = services.AddMvc();
   mvcBuilder.AddJsonOptions(options => {
            // options.SerializerSettings has no setter
            // and this code is run after ConfigureServices is finished
            // so I cannot extract or assign serializerSettings instance here
            options.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime( DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
            options.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
            // configuring AutoMapper here does not work either
        });
        var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
        {
            // how to get this serializerSettings from AddJsonOptions???
            config.AddProfile(new EntityProfile(serializerSettings));
        });

        var mapper = mapperConfiguration.CreateMapper();
        services.AddSingleton(typeof(IMapper), mapper);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
I have ended up doing following to avoid code duplication:

```
    private JsonSerializerSettings ConfigureJsonSettings(JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
        settings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        settings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;
        settings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
        return settings;
    }
```

And then call it twice:

```
mvcBuilder.AddJsonOptions(options => ConfigureJsonSettings(options.SerializerSettings));
ConfigureMapper(services, ConfigureJsonSettings(new JsonSerializerSettings()));
```

I had to replicate configuration like settings.ContractResolver to make sure they are identical. So I still want to know if there is better way to do this soft of configuration.

Comment: Use the values in `serializerSettings` inside the `mvcBuilder.AddJsonOptions` method as parameters for `ConfigureForNodaTime`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your `JsonSerializerSettings` outside of the `AddJsonOptions` method and then use it in a global context for your `MapperConfiguration`.

Example:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
serializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
serializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error;

mvc.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    // have to repeat this because it's an extension method                  
    options.SerializerSettings.ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
    // can get this from the declared settings
    options.SerializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling = serializerSettings.MissingMemberHandling;
});

var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(config =>
{
    // use the already declared settings
    config.AddProfile(new EntityProfile(serializerSettings));
});
```

It's not a great solution because there is duplicate code but this is Startup configuration code so having an extra instance of `JsonSerializerSettings` floating around isn't going to break your app.  It would be easier if the `SerializerSettings` property on the options was settable.